# Difference in MariaDB installation packages on RHEL server?

Tags: rhel7

On trying to install MySql on RHEL7 I came to know that we need to use MariaDB instead.

I tried the installation on my machine which is RHEL6 by adding MariaDB.repo file to /etc/yum.repos.d/ with following lines -

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB-5.5.39
baseurl=https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-5.5.39/yum/rhel6-amd64/
# alternative: baseurl=http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.39/yum/rhel6-amd64/
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/
```

Thereafter I installed it successfully using following command -

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

Now on an RHEL7 production box same steps failed with following conflict -

```
file /etc/my.cnf from install of MariaDB-common-5.5.39-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package maria-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.x86_64
```

So I understand I am pointing to rhel6 repo on rhel7 and probably some pre-installed files are in conflict.

But when I execute below mysql/mariadb gets installed successfully, what difference does case make here?

```
sudo yum install mariadb mariadb-server
```

I am not sure if it is linked to a different repository in background, I dont have access to the instance to dig further in repo settings, can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clarify that using `yum search mariaDB`

I executed that an ended up with same result as mariaDB and mariadb

```
    ============================= N/S matched: mariaDB =============================
    mariadb-bench.x86_64 : MariaDB benchmark scripts and data
    mariadb-devel.i686 : Files for development of MariaDB/MySQL applications
    mariadb-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of MariaDB/MySQL  applications
    mariadb-libs.i686 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
    mariadb-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
    mariadb-server.x86_64 : The MariaDB server and related files
    mariadb.x86_64 : A community developed branch of MySQL
    mariadb-test.x86_64 : The test suite distributed with MariaD

    Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```